# Is it possible to simulate keystrokes in Silverlight (similar to SendKeys)?

Tags: silverlight, sendkeys

Is it possible to build a Silverlight application with an embedded on-screen keyboard that is context aware (e.g. on-screen keyboard appears only when a textbox is in focus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need additional javascript that will show\hide the silverlight app.

For example: User focuses password textbox, javascript fires showing your app. Click on app's virtual keyboard raises javascript that edits textbox.

HTH

Comment: I see no need to use any javascript to do this. You only need javascript if the textbox is in the html, not in your silverlight app.

Comment: Right, I meant that textbox is in the html. If textbox is in the silverlight app there is no need of javascript at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, so I created a Virtual Input Keyboard that can attach to Textboxes and other controls - have a look here:

http://www.orktane.com/Blog/post/2009/11/09/Virtual-Input-Keyboard-Behaviours-for-Silverlight.aspx

Hope that helps, 5 months late though :)

Answer (score 0):

Andrius Mudinas open sourced an excellent Silverlight on-screen keyboard:

http://www.mudinas.com/post/2009/07/10/Silverlight-Keyboard-Control.aspx

We've integrated this into our own Silverlight app.  Remember to copy the keyboard styling from their App.xaml to your project's App.xaml.

You can wire into the KeyPressed event.